# On button click load UserControl without refreshing whole page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Explaining my problem:

In my ASP.NET solution i have 2 buttons:

Button 1 and Button 2

I have two UserControls with totally different content

OnClick of each of those buttons i want to load different UserControl into ContentPlaceHolder, but without reload whole page. So actually it have to work like Ajax TabContainer (but without loading all tabs at once).

I have tried to solve this problem with Ajax TabContainers, but loading times was just awful.

Anyone had same problem? How do u solve this one guys?

Answer (score 1):

`ContentPlaceHolder` I'm assuming is a `div`

You can use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jQuery method. This will load contents of a page into a container via an AJAX call, without refreshing the page.

Used like this:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder').load('ajax/test1.php');
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder').load('ajax/test2.php');
});
```

Comment: ContentPlace holder is <asp:ContentPlaceholder>. i never used php before so dont know syntax, will it be same for asp?

Comment: It does not matter the page extension (in fact, the jQuery documentation uses an HTML page). It will just load the contents of the page into the container.

Comment: `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` is an ASP.NET server tag. It gets translated into actual HTML when the `.aspx` page is parsed.

Comment: Also, you may run into issues using jQuery `.load()`, unless you disable `ViewState`, since those controls did not exist when the page was generated.

Comment: Just found a solution, sorry for wasting your time. Used this solution here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13165/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Tab-Control-Using-the-MultiView-c